# Firebase subscription not updating when I apply a where clause on it

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase subscription in my flutter app that I've setup that works fine, but when I add any where clause on it, the subscription never updates any more. This is how I initialize it, without a where clause:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _loggedIn = true;
        _fooSubscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(FOO_COLLECTION)
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {
          _fooList = [];
          for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
             // process
```

But then when I add a where clause, the subscription never updates even when I add new entries to the collection that satisfy the where clause, for example:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _loggedIn = true;
        _fooSubscription = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(FOO_COLLECTION)
            .where('field', isEqualTo: "foo")
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {
          // THIS ONLY TRIGGERS ONCE ON APP INITIALIZATION 
          _fooList = [];
          for (final document in snapshot.docs) {
             //
```

With the where clause, the subscription only updates on app hard refresh. I can verify that the where clause does return entries that I expect when I hard refresh and see the new entries, but the subscription isn't updating.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here and my googling hasn't pulled anything up yet. Can you not have a where clause on a subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second query requires a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes), which is not auto-created for you.

If you catch and log errors, there should be a message in there with a URL that [opens the Firestore console with all the necessary values filled in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message).

If that doesn't work, you can also [create the necessary composite index manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_console) in the Firestore console.